# Jump one folder up in a URL in Java

Tags: java

I have a URL that I get as below:

```
String jarFilePath = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

This would get me the complete path to the jar file. Now how do I jump one folder up and append some other path to it? For example., if the jarFilePath is something like:

```
c:/path/to/jar/file.jar
```

I want to jump one folder up and append another relative path like below:

```
c:/path/to/resources/path/to/resources/
```

Where the folders resources and jar are at the same directory level in the file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File f = new File("C:/path/to/jar/file.jar");
File dest = new File(f.getParentFile().getParentFile(), "resources/path/to/resources");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and use a `File` object:

```
File jarFile = new File(jarFilePath);
File newFolder = new File( jarFile.getParentFile().getParentFile(), "resources/path/to/resources");
```

If you want to use the path as a string, try using Apache Commons IO's [`FilenameUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html):

```
String resourcesPath = FilenameUtils.normalize( FilenameUtils.getPath(jarFilePath) + "/../resources/path/to/resources");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the File-Object, that makes a lot of things easier:
    import java.io.File;

```
String pathname = "c:/path/to/jar/file.jar";
File f = new File(pathname);
String p = f.getParent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways.

- You can split the path into it's elements and rebuild it until `array.length -3` (-1 would be filename, -2 the last folder)
- You could simple remove the file and append another `../` (which just means: "Go one directory back") (that would be something like this then: `c:/path/to/jar/../resources/path/to/resources/`)
- You gould use a regex to get rid of the last folder and file. something like `/[^/]+/[^/]+$`

Comment: oh yeah - or use the fileobject :P